# Flex Mobile Devlopement: Small views on Nexus 5

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder

I just started developing Android/iOS apps using Flex..

I have a question about difference reason between testing the app on a real device ( Nexus 5 ) and Flash Builder Emulator ( Samsung Galaxy Ace )

You can see the Actionbar has a good look on Samsung Galaxy Ace:

[image: Samsung Galaxy Ace]

And in the real device Nexus 5 it is very small:

[image: Nexus 5]

I have developed a lot of apps using Android SDK and when I test my custom design and android design, it's look good on any device but in Flex I tried a lot to fix that but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you use multi dpi techniques?

Comment: In mutilDPI techniques your application is scale as per their device/screen DPI. you have to just adjust for onlu only dpi.
 You have to look at following links. 
**1.**  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html
**2.**  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile-skinning-part2.html

Comment: Hi @ketan, the links that you attached help me to understand multi dpi techniques.. thank you a lot

Comment: Ok so, i posted it as a answer so, it will help to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dpi concept for your application for different device/screen DPI. Here in given links describe the DPI concept for flex.

**1.** http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html

**2.** http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile-skinning-part2.html

You have to apply design for any perticular DPI it. Then it will automatically scale for other DPI. like: `applicationDPI="160"`.

You can icon property of button like:

```
<s:Button>
 <s:icon> 
     <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource source160dpi="@Embed('/assets/refresh160.png')" 
                             source240dpi="@Embed('/assets/refresh240.png')" 
                             source320dpi="@Embed('/assets/refresh320.png')"/> 
 </s:icon> 
</s:Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

flex's internal dpi scaling doesn't adequately handle the newer android screen resolutions of more than 360 dpi. I've encountered the same issue on devices such as the Nexus 4, Samsung S4 & S5, Huawei Honor 6, etc. - which have resolutions at or close to 445 dpi.

Unless someone has found a more elegant solution, my way of attacking this is to detect 360+ dpi devices when the application starts up, and apply individual scaleX/scaleY adjustments to all components in the app that don't rely solely on percent size designations. Adobe needs to add 400 and 480 dpi constants to their applicationDpi options.